# awk split question

Tags: awk, split

I wrote a small script, using awk 'split' command to get the current directory name.

echo $PWD

I need to replace '8' with the number of tokens as a result of the split operation.
// If PWD = /home/username/bin. I am trying to get "bin" into package.

```
package="`echo $PWD | awk '{split($0,a,"/"); print a[8] }'`" 
echo $package
```

Can you please tell me what do I substitute in place of 'print a[8]'  to get the script working for any directory path ?

-Sachin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need awk for that. If you always want the last dir in a path just do:

```
#!/bin/sh

cur_dir="${PWD##*/}/"
echo "$cur_dir"
```

The above has the added benefit of not creating any subshells and/or forks to external binaries.  It's all native POSIX shell syntax.

Comment: try: `$ cd /; echo ${PWD##*/}`

Comment: Or `basename $(dirname $PWD)`

Comment: @Tomasz fair enough.  A simple appending of a '/' should clear that right up.

Comment: @dmckee: It wasn't suggestion of other possible solution, but an use case in which SegeX's solution will fail; Your solution on the other hand will print $PWD's parent directory name and will fail if directory name contains spaces

Comment: @dmckee You just forked off 3 processes to accomplish the same thing that the shell can do natively. Actually, Tomasz is right, that isn't the same thing, `basename "$PWD"` is though. Still, a superfluous fork.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `print a[length(a)]` but it's better to avoid splitting and use custom fields separator and `$NF`:

```
echo $PWD | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
```

But in that specific case you should rather use `basename`:

```
basename "$PWD"
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are better replacements to perform the function you're trying to accomplish. However, here is the specific answer to your question:

```
package=$(echo $PWD | awk '{n = split($0,a,"/"); print a[n] }')
echo "$package"
```

`split()` returns the number of resulting elements.